# Can’t find NetTcpActivator service

Tags: windows, iis, net-tcp

I have walked across services window from bottom to top and couldn’t find that on my machine with Windows 10. But I have found it easy on another computer under windows 7. Maybe I need to do something to find that, can anybody gives tip and/or help?

Comment: Delete the question if you resolved it. Or post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by myself: 
Open “Enabling and Disabling Windows components” window and under .Net Framework 4.7 find WCF services you will find TCP activator. Install this component and service will be accessible